Jupyter notebook not displaying properly
This question is very similar to Jupyter Notebook not displaying correctly after reinstall which does not have a satisfactory answer.
A few months ago I was fiddling around with the preferences of Jupyter notebook using guidance from CoPilot! All I managed to do was to change the look of the pages. The following is an example.

Further changes uner the guidence of copilot broke the whole thing so I had to uninstall Anaconda and reinstall. Everything now works but the look of the pages remains as above.
I have finally got around to trying to sort it out without success. I assume there is a CSS file which is causing this but I cannot find it.
The things I have tried are

changed browser
looked at the page using developers tools. The css is supposed to reside in ~\custom\custom.css. I have found 2 files with that description in the Anaconda3 tree but both are empty.
before reinstalling I deleted all the anaconda3 directory so I think it must be coming from somewhere else.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Not sure what you are really asking about here?  "...but the look of the pages remains as above." Okay. But what is the problem there? Have you examined the version numbers of Jupyter Notebook before and after you updated things. It looks to me like you are using Jupyter Notebook 7+ and not realizing things have changed dramatically in Jupyter in the last year or so. This doesn't look like the other post you reference. Are you able to run cells? There execution didn't work and everything else was about the user not understanding about the updated version.

I believe there is a css file that is being used which should not be there and is changeing how the pages look. It does not seem to be overwritten when reloading Anaconda

Except for the green dot being slightly smaller maybe, and that could just be due to your browser zoom settings(?), I don't see much of any difference with what you show there in that image and what I see when I launch into Jupyter Notebook 7 using the  'launch binder' button here. So I wonder if you think you changed things but in fact did not and the difference is you are just using Jupyter Notebook 7+ and not realizing? (Which is what I already said, but I hadn't looked at the example side by side recently.) If not, ...

 can you please indicate what you believe it should look like? You maybe can use that resource there or others available from here to see what you should see, especially in separate fresh browsers.

They are remarkably similar. Maybe I am chasing my tail. When the change happened there certainly was a difference but maybe Jupyter has changed its look. Thank you for your help.

"...but maybe Jupyter has changed its look." Jupyter has dramatically changed its look as everything is built on JupyterLab components now. See the middle section of my answer here for links highlighting this. "Further changes uner the guidence of copilot broke the whole thing so I had to uninstall Anaconda and reinstall." When you first broke things and then had to reinstall, you got the current Anaconda Distribution which adopted Jupyter Notebook 7+ several months ago now. Prior to that it was using NbClassic or earlier equivalents.

Thanks, but before it was completely broken and reinstalled it did look different to what it had looked like 15mins before. I had seen this happen before when I had problems installing Pytorch but that disappeared after reinstallation of everything.
